# ajax post does not send data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, post, ckeditor

I have this ajax-post:

```
$.ajax({
  url: Config.Proxy + "ContentPages.aspx?t=save",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: {
    content: content,
    id: currentPageId,
    active: "true",
    subject: $('#txtSubject').val(),
    webid: webid
  },
  success: function (data, status) {
    // do something
  },
  error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

I do a post to an .NET page, so I could use the debug mode to check if the data is send correctly.
I use the same code as above for a different page (other url, other data).

When I run the application and save the data I don't come in the debug mode. When I use the same code for the other page, it works fine.

I tried to compare both codes, but they are the same. I have removed some data-items, but it still does not work.

Why? Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

- EDIT *
  I know why this is happening: CKEditor. As soon as I set the variable "content" to the content of the CKEditor and use the post-call, the debug-mode is not called anymore. Also the form-keys in the code-behind are 0.
  The question now is how to fix this?

Comment: could you post ContentPages code?

Comment: No need, figured out how this is happening: CKEditor. As soon as I set the variable "content" to the content of the CKEditor and use the post-call, the debug-mode is not called anymore. Also the form-keys in the code-behind are 0. (see my edit in the original post for more info)

Comment: Interesting that you post the client side code and not the server side. You can inspect the XHR requests in your browser, but you will see that the post does what you configured. Need more info to help.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the edit of my original post: Problem was caused by the content of the CKEditor. I think HTML is not parser/loaded/call-it-what-you-want in an AJAX-post.
So, with a little help (and without posting code-behind, that had nothing to do with the problem) I figured it out:

```
var content = escape(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData());
```

Put the variable "content" in the data-section of the post and voila! It works like a charm.

On the receiving .NET page in code behind, decode the value:

```
(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form.Get("content").NullSafeString())
```

Thanks anyway